# Beginner loop writing: compute angle between two points in array, filter data (matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I have two data sets with over a million points. What I want to do is create a loop that looks at each position x1, x2, y1, y2 and computes the angle between those two points. From there I want to delete points if the angle (a) between them is  -0.5 > a < 0.5 (so like if angle -0.5 > a < 0.5, delete corresponding x2,y2,z2, save remaining points as a text file).

I know that I can use atan2((y2-y1, x2-x1)) but I can't figure out how to do a loop for this array. I also have z data that I need to retain for each point in the second dataset (x2, y2).

Comment: please clarify what you mean by the angle between two points and for what points you want to compare it. I suppose you do not want to compare each point from the first array with each one from the second? that would pretty much delete all points...

Comment: sorry they are two vectors- one is coordinates in an image, the other is a vector of point normals. by comparing the two vectors I can get the angle between them. I'm doing this to get rid of any horizontal normals (normals with an angle close to 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, two points can't form an angle, so, I'm going to assume that you are referring to the angles of the vectors from P1(x1,y1) to P2(x2,y2). With this in mind, you can do something like this:

```
N = 100;
threshold = 0.5;

P0 = zeros(N,2);
P1 = [cos( ((1:N)/N)*2*pi )' sin( ((1:N)/N)*2*pi )'];

ang = atan2(P1(:,2) - P0(:,2), P1(:,1) - P0(:,1) );
sel = abs(ang) < threshold; 

newP0 = P0(~sel,:);
newP1 = P1(~sel,:);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am referring to vectors, sorry for the confusion.

Would this go through all the points in the image? And would it retain the z points (aka column 3)? 

Just confused since I assumed I would need a for loop for this. Maybe not?

Comment: wait now I'm confused what you assigned P0 and P1. Say I input my vector 1 as P1 and vector 2 as P0, I assume I can just use your any and sell forumlas to obtain the values I need?

Comment: In my answer `ang` is the angle you have marked as `atan2((y2-y1, x2-x1))` in your question. `sel` is a logical vector which has a value of `1` where `abs(ang) < threshold` and `0` elsewhere. What I meant in my previous comment was that `P0` and `P1` need to be Nx2 matrices. I know I referred to them as vectors, that was my bad.

Comment: but if they're Nx2 I won't be able to retain the 3rd column I need to (the Z information for my xyz vectors)

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I forgot about that part. `P0` and `P1` need to be _at least_ Nx2 - , where the first two columns are the x and y coordinates of your vectors. If there are more than 2 columns, these will be retained in `newP0` and `newP1`. Alternatively, if you keep the your Z information in a separate vector, you can use `sel` to select from that too by `newZ = S(~sel)`.